# How to use CircleImageView library ( this : 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0' ) inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

[This is the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0aRN.png)I'm trying to use this library in fragment inside onViewCreated() method, but i'm getting this casting error: -   java.lang.ClassCastException:androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView. I don't know how to solve this error. can anybody please help me?
FragmentProfile.java :

```
public class FragmentProfile extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
            Button sign_out;
            TextView user_number;
            private CircleImageView userImage;
        
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        
                sign_out = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_logout);
                userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_display_name);
                user_number = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        
                sign_out.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class));
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
```

```
fragment_profile.xml
    
      
     
    
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_180"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/money" />
    
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_95"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_95"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_140"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/textColor"
            app:civ_border_width="@dimen/dp_2" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balsamiq_sans_bold"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/border"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sp_22" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/user_logout"
            android:layout_below="@id/user_display_name"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_12"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_12"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_30"
                android:fontFamily="@font/balsamiq_sans_bold"
                android:text="+91-987654321"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dp_18" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/user_logout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_200"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:text="@string/sign_out"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // ... rest of the codes.
    // Comment out code below.
    // userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_display_name);
    // Replace it with code below.
    userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    // ... rest of the codes.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry, I didn't see that my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are parsing a textview id to the CircleImageView.  You should change your `userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_display_name);` to `userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.profile_image);`.  That's why you are getting java.lang.ClassCastException:androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView exception.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is here:

```
private CircleImageView userImage;
userImage =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.user_display_name);
```

and in your layout:

```
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/user_display_name"
```

You **can not** cast a `TextView` into a `CircleImageView`.